Realtek RTL8125 2.5gb ( Gigabyte z790 elite ax motherboard card ) slow transfer speed
im trying to understand from about 2 days why i can't get the same speed transfer that i have on Windows11.
I will explain better what i mean.
I have an UnRaid server that share a folder over SMB with 2.5gb eth card.
I have a PC with dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 11 also this pc has a Realtek 2.5gb eth.
When i transfer big files from the PC booted on windows inside the shared folder of UnRaid server , the transfer speed is about 280/285 MBytes.
When i do the same thing from Ubuntu the transfer speed can't go over 180Mbytes.
I need to understand why this is happening because i have a disk with linux_raid_member file system mounted on Ubuntu that i can't mount on Windows 11.
It contains over 12TBytes of media file that i need to transfer into the UnRaid server, and im loosing about 100MBytes/s transfer speed that means hours i have to wait more.
I have time to try to resolve the issue bacause i can't still start the transfer job.
Any tips ? Im not a Linux expert neither a Network expert.
Any help will be appreciated.
